# How to read the head section of a web page?

Tags: php, javascript

On my web page, when the user types in a URL in the text field, I wan to get some information about that page, like title or link information.

Is there way to do it? On the client (JavaScript) or on the server (PHP)? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server:

need [simpledom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
    include("simpledom.php");
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
    echo $html->find('head')->outertext; // returns <head>...</head>
```

Comment: If you want the same functionality without a 3rd party library, the SimpleXML and DomXML libraries included in PHP both support xpath queries.  The syntax is a bit more verbose, but it's bound to perform better, and will keep your set of installed libraries smaller.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it through Javascript, unless the page is in your domain. This is because cross-server scripting is restricted.

But you can use PHP (check `file_get_contents()` function), parse the content of the `<head>`  tag with simpledom and then pass it to an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can open URLs like files, i.e.

```
$f = fopen ("http://www.site/page.htm", r);
```

If you want to actually use a real DOM then use simpledom or another module.

Edit: You can probably ignore the fopen() suggestion above, for some reason I was thinking you were asking only about reading sites that you had full control of.

Comment: most webhosts block allow_url_fopen these days. It will be disabled altogether in PHP6. A better option would be cURL if you need your application to support PHP6 or your webhost has disabled allow_url_fopen.

Comment: My initial assumption was that he was reading a site that he controlled, which upon reflection was a poor one.

cURL is certainly an option although I think I'd still probably tend toward a simpledom-stype module.

Answer (score 0):

So, you page have an input text box, and when your user types in a link you want to retrieve information about it?

This might be useful:

http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/load/

According to that page that would return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Date] => Mon, 18 Jun 2007 13:56:22 GMT
            [Server] => Apache/2.0.54 (Unix) PHP/4.4.7 mod_ssl/2.0.54 OpenSSL/0.9.7e mod_fastcgi/2.4.2 DAV/2 SVN/1.4.2
            [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.2.2
            [Expires] => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
            [Cache-Control] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
            [Pragma] => no-cache
            [Set-Cookie] => PHPSESSID=85g9n1i320ao08kp5tmmneohm1; path=/
            [Last-Modified] => Tue, 30 Nov 1999 00:00:00 GMT
            [Vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked
            [Content-Type] => text/xml
        )
    [body] => ... Contents of the Page ...
    [info] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://www.bin-co.com/rss.xml.php?section=2
            [content_type] => text/xml
            [http_code] => 200
            [header_size] => 501
            [request_size] => 146
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 1.113792
            [namelookup_time] => 0.180019
            [connect_time] => 0.467973
            [pretransfer_time] => 0.468035
            [size_upload] => 0
            [size_download] => 2274
            [speed_download] => 2041
            [speed_upload] => 0
            [download_content_length] => 0
            [upload_content_length] => 0
            [starttransfer_time] => 0.826031
            [redirect_time] => 0
        )
```

)

Comment: he wants the <head> section, not the headers.